# Populate DropDown List using JQuery in ASP.NET MVC (Active Directory request)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, active-directory

EDIT: The below code works, for anybody who would need!

This question is asked alot but couldn't find help for this specific one. I need to show a dropdown list that loads while I type in a search bar. While I type, I need to search in Active Directory for the Username that is being typed, and then it shows in the dropdown list all the options (say, it would only show results after 4 characters).

I have a simple form with one input, one button, a controller function to search user from a C# class that allows me to acces the AD. I put the JQuery script which retrieves data. The data is being correctly fetched but I cannot show it in the autocomplete. Any ideas?

The form:

```
    <form class="form-inline" method="post" action="~/Home/SearchUserResult">
        <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInput"> Nom et/ou Prénom </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" name="searchName" id="searchName" placeholder="Nom et/ou prénom"/>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="searchValidate"> Rechercher </button>
    </form>
```

My AD search function:

```
    public List<string> SearchUserByName(string name)
    {
        try
        {
            SearchResultCollection resultCollection;
            DirectoryEntry ldapConnection = createDirectoryEntry();
            DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(ldapConnection);


            search.Filter = "(anr=" + name + ")";
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayName");
            resultCollection = search.FindAll();

            if (resultCollection.Count == 0)
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                foreach(SearchResult sResult in resultCollection)
                {
                    lastName.Add(sResult.Properties["displayName"][0].ToString());
                }
            }
            return lastName;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception caught:\n\n" + e.ToString());
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Here is the Controller function suggest by @caner

```
public ActionResult SearchUserByName(string name)
{
    ADManager adManager = new ADManager();
    List<string> lastName = adManager.SearchUserByName(name);
    if (lastName != null)
    {
        ViewData["Names"] = lastName;
        return Json(lastName,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Finally here is the script I have for now, it gets the data but does not show it (in alert(data) I retrieve all the info I need):

```
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#searchName").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/Home/SearchUserByName",
                        type: "GET",
                        data: { name: $("#searchName").val() },
                        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "JSON",
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert(data)
                            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    label: item
                                }
                            }));
                        },
                    });
                },
                minLength: 4
            })
        });
    </script>
```

Thanks for your help

EDIT: createDirectoryEntry() is a function I made just to create connection to AD.
EDIT 2 : If you have any other ideas to do that with something else than JQuery, I'm open to everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script works for me:

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            $("#searchName").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/Home/SearchUserByName",
                        type: "GET",
                        data: { name: $("#searchName").val() },
                        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "JSON",
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert(data)
                            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    label: item
                                }
                            }));
                        },
                    });
                },
                minLength: 4
            })
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try jquery autocomplete like this...

your script:

```
 $(function () {
       $("#searchName").autocomplete({
           source: function (request, response) {                    
                   $.ajax({
                        url: "/YourController/SearchUserByName",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: { name: $("#searchName").val() },
                        dataType: "JSON",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data.lastName, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    label: item
                                }
                            }));
                        },
                    });
                },
                minLength: 4
          })
 });
```

and your controller method:

```
public ActionResult SearchUserByName(string name)
{
     .
     .
     .

     return Json(lastName);
}
```

Comment: Ok I'm trying, but I get error saying object can't handle autocomplete from javascript. In my header I have jquery script src and JQuery UI script src.

Comment: Ok I found a fix. On the other hand, when I type in the search bar I get no results found, where valdating the form does give me the results I want. Btw thank you for the help :)

Comment: probably jquery library issue... glad to help :)

Comment: Do you think it could be because of the type of lastName object? How does JQuery know it's a list I'm giving it?

Comment: is the debuger hitting your `SearchUserByName`?

Comment: you are returning `json` not `list<string>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144477/discussion-between-caner-and-flexabust-bergson).